# How to increase the size of a Google Cloud virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform

How does Google Cloud handle increasing or decreasing the size of a VM i.e. changing the RAM and CPU options.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This behavior has now changed, and instances are customizable before and after creation. However, the instance must be shutdown in order to edit it and increase it's RAM or/and CPU. More information is available in this Help Center [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance).

Comment: I wonder if it's a limitation (that memory and disk cannot be increased dynamically) set by Google or there is a technical reason why a VM's memory cannot be scaled up and down on the fly?

Comment: @DmitriLihhatsov disk could be updated at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

you can stop the instance and manipulate the memory or cpu which ever you need and start he instance after you have made your necessary changes

Comment: You have to wait for some time after shutting down (or stopping) the instance

Answer (score 1):

Once a machine has been created, you cannot increase the RAM or CPU. this is only done when first instantiated.

However, there is a workaround. From the **Developers Console**, you will need to snapshot the existing VM disk, delete the machine, create a new one (choose the CPU and RAM according to your needs, and where it says "**Boot disk**" choose "**New Disk from snapshot**" and select the snapshot you created earlier).

I know it sounds a bit laborious but actually it is pretty straight-forward, should not take you more than a couple of minutes.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks very much - it would be great to have ability to increase and decrease with one or two clicks.