# How to increase Google compute engine RAM and Disk

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have hosted a wordpress on Google Compute engine,kindly find the below specification.

Kindly see the specification.

Instance type=f1-micro

Memory=0.60GB

Virtual core=1

I followed the instruction given at below link.

[How to increase the size of a Google Cloud virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128599/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-google-cloud-virtual-machine)

I created created snapshot of existing VM and attached that snapshot to new VM.

But when i iam opening the new VM ip it is not working.

Kindly advice how increase RAM and Disk of Existing VM.

With thanks and regards,
Vijay Maurya

Answer (score 1):

So far only found this dialog under "[recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-sizing-recommendations-for-instances)".

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does this let us continue with all the work we've already done?

Comment: A more comprehensive guide can be found [here](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/google-cloud-persistent-disk-how-to-resize-and-use)

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify the machine configurations, you have to stop the VM instance first.
Then go to edit, and change the machine type with required memory.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have to go into the Networks section under Compute and then assign the old IP address to the new machine. That's what I did when upgrading one of my instances.

Comment: Downvoted because then we'd have to ditch our established work.  I'm pretty sure you can just add space to the disk.  Maybe this answer is appropriate for changing the RAM, but not for disk